# How to optimize my MongoDB query that involves aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need some help in optimizing a lookup where the source collection has 8 Million records and the lookup collection has around 170K records.

MongoDB playground -  https://mongoplayground.net/p/px3vF039Wiw

Currently, even with the right indices, the query takes 8 seconds. I am just getting started with MongoDB and it would be great if someone can help me optimize my query.

Comment: You can also refer: [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).

Comment: Just a hint, instead of projection all fields one by one, you may use `{$mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$match"]}`

Comment: Provided you have the correct indexes there is not much you can do. What is the explain plan?

Comment: I hope "right indices" mean at least: ipv4_addresses.geoname_id and locations.geoname_id